# Java unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, filenotfoundexception

I am confused currently as to why I am receiving "unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException." when I try to run my code. I am taking in a file path from the main method arguments, and catching the error in the instance that the input path is wrong or that the file cannot be found in the path.

Could someone please give me a hand with this? Here's my code for this part:

```
public void readFile(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath) throws IOException{

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    File input = null;

    try{
    input = new File(inputFilePath);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("Input file cannot be found in the provided path");
    }
```

Comment: The constructor `File(String)` doesn't throw `FileNotFoundException` .

Comment: File objects are merely references to file or directory paths that may or may not exist, which is why the `File` type has an `exists()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this line

`input = new File(inputFilePath);`

doesn't throw  FileNotFoundException

If you dig into the code of `new File(..)` this is what it has

```
public File(String pathname) {
     if (pathname == null) {
         throw new NullPointerException();
     }
     this.path = fs.normalize(pathname);
     this.prefixLength = fs.prefixLength(this.path);
}
```

as you can see this method doesn't throw `FileNotFoundException`, there is only possibility of NPE.

If you were to extend your code to read the file like this

```
new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(input));
```

then `FileNotFoundException` makes sense. Try it out.

Comment: I'm confused because when I deliberately messed the path up it gave me FileNotFoundException, and when I debugged it was on the new File() creation.

Comment: that is not possible with only this line `new File(inputFilePath)` as far as i know. can you give me an example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I think it might actually be the Scanner directly under the File declaration line. I looked at the api and it looks like that Scanner throws FileNotFoundException. I just learned of File exists() method, so I should probably use that instead